# How can I navigate to another widget by using onSubmitted in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to navigate to another widget using `onSubmitted` in `TextField()` in Flutter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"? There is a concept of routes in Flutter, but I could also imagine that you mean focus. Can you clarify?

Comment: I want to use Navigate.push() and MaterialPageRourte() but I was not able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Navigator.push()` in the `onSubmitted`.
Like the Example below.

```
TextField(
        onSubmitted: (value){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "Search",
          suffixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```